# Confused myself with matrix and array addition

Tags: python, arrays

I was doing some practice with lists, arrays and matrices in python and I got confused at something.

if I do:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [2,3,4,5]

print list1 + list2
```

**Output:**

```
I get [1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5]
```

I think it was like yesterday I was doing something similar but I got

**Output2:**

```
[3,5,7,9]
```

the actual addition of the values of each respective element on both lists. But I was actually expecting it to be the first output, but it added the values.

I haven't done linear algebra or prob&stats in a while. What was the method called for the output I got in output1? and output2? I've confused myself bad.

**edit:** http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.add.html
If you look at the 2nd example they do a 3x3 array + 1x3 array. I thought if there not the same dimension you can't add them?

Comment: Lists and arrays have entirely different behavior. Always be careful which one you're using. `np.matrix` is awful; don't use it.

Comment: Lists are lists, vectors are vectors. The `+` operator concatenates two lists. If you want vectorised addition, either use `numpy` arrays or subclass `list` and overload arithmetic methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using standard lists, addition is defined as concatenation of the two lists

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [2,3,4,5]

print list1 + list2
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When using numpy types, addition is defined as element-wise addition rather than list concatenation.

```
array1 = np.array(list1)
array2 = np.array(list2)

print array1 + array2
# [3 5 7 9]
```

This is often called a [vectorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) operation. In cases where arrays are large it can be faster than iterating over the structures, since the vectorized operation utilize a highly optimized implementation which is provided by numpy.

Comment: Maybe nice to add to this answer, is that the numpy variant is called vectorizing.

Comment: @Caramiriel Thanks for the suggestion. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not understand `zip` or `numpy` - 
Assuming both lists `list1` and `list2` have same length, this will do your work

```
[a[i]+b[i] for i in xrange(len(a))]
```

PS: simply using `list1 + list2` would only concatenate these two lists.
To add each of the element you need to iterate through the lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can get "Output2" canonically with `sum()` and `zip()`:

```
result = [sum(item) for item in zip(list1, list2)]
```

If you put each `list1`, `list2`, etc. into a container (such as a `tuple` or another `list`, e.g. `lists = [list1, list2]`) you can instead use `zip(*lists)` and then not have to change that code for any quantity of `list`s.